# Android layoutAnimation in TabWidget

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the TabHost Activity to animate every time the tab is tapped? Right now i have the animation applied to the Activity that appears under the tab, but it will only every animate once (the first time it is loaded). Its a simple animation of the View coming in from left to right.

Comment: Hello, Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should add onResume() method and do the same thing as the onCreate() in the activity. Then the animation should appears every time you tap it.